# Dealing with flash erase time

Tags: stm32, interrupts, flash, usb-device

I am trying to use an STM32 micro-controller as a USB mass storage device using an AT25SF041 flash  chip for the memory. I know flash integrity degrades over time but its only going to have a file written once or twice during it's lifetime.

My problem is the erase cycle for a 4 KB sector is about 60-300 ms. An interrupt routine is called named
STORAGE_write_FS() and my psuedocode for the rest is as follows

```
STORAGE_Write_FS(){
  Erase chip
  loop(16 times){
    write segment of 256bytes
  {
}
```

The problem is i need a way to make sure at least 300ms has passed before writing the bytes.

I am using the SPI library as my chip does not have an FSMC peripheral and so the timings are not directly configurable.

What is the best way to do this without using the HAL_delay(); function?

If I return USBD_BUSY then the device sends a NYET command to the host PC saying its not ready yet.
I'm thinking I could use the systick to evaluate the amount of time that has passed without changing the interrupt flow.

If so, how could I best implement this?

and please give an example if you can. I learn best that way.

Comment: I think you're looking at this wrong by asking "What is the best way to do this without using a delay?". You have to have a delay - whether it's a simple "do nothing for a fixed period of time" or it's a smarter "check the Flash every couple of mSec to see when it's done" - it's still a delay. Your real problem is that your `STORAGE_Write_FS()` is an interrupt routine, and that's what's causing your (justified) concern over having a delay (which is unavoidable). Take the bulk of `STORAGE_Write_FS()` out of the interrupt context and put it in your `main()` loop. Use the interrupt to trigger it.

Comment: @brhans I'm not sure what you mean. The STORAGE_Write_FS is the interrupt routine (or callback, not really sure). It's a function that came with the library.

Comment: You could end the interrupt when you need to wait but just before you exit, set up another interrupt to fire based on a timer to continue things.

Comment: Don't do any of the Flash operations inside the interrupt or callback. Just set a flag to indicate that it needs to be done. Then back in your main loop, check the flag - if it's set then do the Flash stuff, then clear it. While the flag remains set, report a Busy state back to the PC.